# Sql query to capture minimum date, max date based on row ordering upto null

Tags: sql, database, oracle, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

Agenda is to track hiring and rehiring scenario for a resource

```
empID   emp_Status      CreateDate      end_date
1       active          **2019-02-01**  Null
1       active          2019-02-02      2019-01-04 (Skipped because last day is greater than joining date)
1       active          2019-02-03      Null
1       Terminated      2019-02-04      **2019-02-02**
1       Terminated      2019-02-05      2019-02-02
1       active          2019-02-06      Null
```

Output should able to track joining date and last workday and respective count

output:

```
empID   join_date       last_date       Joining_count
1       2019-02-01      2019-02-02      1
1       2019-02-06      Null            2
```

I need to achieve this in redshift or oracle sql query. Please help me through this.

Comment: can you put the create table and insert scripts to try out for users, it will be waste of time to write it and help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, for each "new" active, you want the next "terminated".  One method is to create groups with a reverse count of terminated and then aggregation:

```
select empid,
       min(case when emp_status = 'active' then createdate end) as active_date,
       min(case when emp_status = 'Terminated' then createdate end) as terminate_date,
       row_number() over (partition by empid order by min(createdate)) as joining_count
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when emp_status = 'Terminated' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by empid order by createdate desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by empid, grp
having sum(case when emp_status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5211d2f7cebd59f65c2852cea20e13b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: There are multiple terminated and active values in rows, This actually gives 1st row of output and not 2nd row rite.

Comment: @SuhasC . . . For some reason, you capitalize `'Terminated'` but not `'active'`, which is the reason for one row in the result set.  There was another but of adding an additional row, but I have fixed that as well.